# error: vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, iterator

This is the line which causes the error

```
vector<transform>::iterator transformIter;
    for (transformIter = (*objIter)->transforms.begin(); transformIter != (*objIter)->transforms.end(); objIter++) {
                    handleTransform((*transformIter));
                }
```

It occurs on the second iteration of the loop regardless of how many transofrms are in the vector.

The obj struct looks like this:

```
struct obj {

    vector<glm::vec4> vertices;
    vector<int> elements;
    vector<object> objects;
    vector<transform> transforms;


};
```

and the function handleTransform is:

```
void handleTransform(transform currentTransform) {

    if (currentTransform.type == 'r') {
        glRotatef(currentTransform.coordinates.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(currentTransform.coordinates.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(currentTransform.coordinates.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    if (currentTransform.type == 's') {
        glScalef(currentTransform.coordinates.x, currentTransform.coordinates.y, currentTransform.coordinates.z);
    }

    if (currentTransform.type == 't') {
        glTranslatef(currentTransform.coordinates.x, currentTransform.coordinates.y, currentTransform.coordinates.z);
    }

}
```

Iterating through the other vectors in an obj doesn't cause any vector issues, so I have to imagine it's something to do with the handleTransform function, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: can you post the exact error message? By the way, you take the argument by value, thereby creating a copy of it. Is that what you would like to do?

Comment: You're saying I'm taking a copy of the transform in the function handleTransform?  That should be fine, since i Just need the values in the current transform to perform the OpenGL translations with them (no data is going to be modified in the function).  And here's the whole error: http://puu.sh/gBtZE/7145785c7d.png

Comment: "press retry to debug the application". Did you try that? Did you compile as debug?

Comment: Passing a constant reference is like passing a pointer, less to pass means it will be a little more effective, and marking it's as constant may allow the compiler some extra optimizations as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Passing const reference is good but how could it allow extra optimizations?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: a const reference doesn't tell the referenced object is constant, but only that you cannot mutate it **using that reference**: the object can still mutate because of aliasing or other accesses. The optimizer simply totally ignores const-ness of references... that concept was designed as an aid for programmers, not for the compiler (I'm also not sure at all it really helps the programmers, but that's another story).

Answer (score 1):

You are erroneously incrementing `objIter`, not `transformIter`:

```
for (transformIter = (*objIter)->transforms.begin(); 
     transformIter != (*objIter)->transforms.end(); 
     objIter++) // ??
```

It should be:

```
for (transformIter = (*objIter)->transforms.begin(); 
     transformIter != (*objIter)->transforms.end(); 
     ++transformIter)
```

To avoid mistakes like this, use `std::for_each`, or if using C++ 11, a ranged-based `for` loop:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

With either of these options, you eliminate the need to declare iterators, make mistakes iterating to the next item, or if not those issues, perform a post-increment instead of a faster pre-increment of the iterator (as your original code is doing).

Answer (score 1):

Replace `objIter++` by `++transformIter`.